# Should one read the story of the cursing of Canaan in a different way?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parashat-noach, curse, canaan

The verses of Genesis 9: 24-27 are generally believed to be part of a larger context, including the verses 9: 20-23. In other words, that these verses together tell one (a complete) story. But what if they are to be viewed separately? What if Cham sees Noach after he gets drunk and falls asleep, and then asks his brothers for help and puts him to rest elsewhere? When Noah wakes up at a later time, however, (it appears as if) something has happened in the meantime that Noah is aware of . And although the story in such a case does not record what happened, it becomes clear that Canaan has something to do with it, and this could be a good reason why Noach curses Canaan and not Cham.

Could the story be understood in such a way?

P.s. If not, does the grammar used to tell the story provide any solution to get out of the Cham who saw the nakedness of Noach, and Canaan ending up being the one cursed by Noach, situation? Is it possible for example to read a verse like 9:22 as: "And Cham saw his father, Canaan the nakedness of his forefather, and he (Cham or Canaan) went out to tell his brethren outside (or out in the open)."

I already looked at [another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13276/why-did-noach-curse-canaan-and-not-cham), but I'm not so much looking for commentaries/interpretations which add to the text, I'm rather looking for options within grammar or punctuation which helps us understand the context in another way; For example the wording 'nakedness of his father' is sometimes taken literally (Noach being naked) but also often in the way it is described elsewhere such as Leviticus 18:8, 20:11 and Deuteronomy 27:20 (refering to some sort of incest, thus the nakedness of the wife of Noach), which makes it possible to read the exact same verse in a totally different way.

Comment: Also related - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118080/was-noah-or-his-wife-the-direct-victim-in-genesis-9/118081#118081

Comment: If your question is "could?" the answer is "of course!". If your answer is "are there Rabbis that took this approach?" the answer is "I don't know of".